# How to get output and get sum of columns in array / matrix?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, output

hello to all you code geniuses on here
ill try to explain my problem as simply as i can

image1

[image]

---

To produce image1, lets say an array like below is required, keeping in mind that the numbers are placed left to right in the first row, then go backwards in the second row, and if you added more numbers, it would create a third row.

```
int[] something = {1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2}
```

---

so i want to make to make a "map" of the layout, like this desired output below.

```
2 1 1 3 3 1

1 2 3 2 1 2
```

and then from there i would want to find the total for each column, so like this.

```
2 1 1 3 3 1

1 2 3 2 1 2

..................

3 3 4 5 4 3
```

(and i then want to make store this layout and sum within another array)

hopefully that all made sense, if so,
how could i go about doing this?

thanks heaps : )

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can use a two-dimensional array data structure to solve this:

```java
int[][] something = new int[][]{
    {2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1},
    {1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2}
};

int totalForColomn1 = something[0][0] + something [1][0];
int totalForColomn2 = something[0][1] + something [1][1];
// ...
int totoalForColomn6 = something[0][5] + something [1][5];
```

If you could only use one-dimensional array:

```java
int[] something = new int[] {2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2};
int row_size = 6;

int totalForColomn1 = something[0] + something[0 + row_size];
int totalForColomn2 = something[1] + something[1 + row_size];
// ...
int totalForColomn6 = something[5] + something[5 + row_size];
```

Remember to keep a consistant `row_size` by putting those undecided element to 0.
In this [case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tmek.jpg), you should init your array like:

```java
int[] something = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1};
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but, what if the "something" array could only be single dimension

Comment: Wow, it's kind of weird, let me think.

Comment: @5KRU6 Can you ensure each row has the same amount of numbers? If yes, it could be easier.

Comment: the rows / columns should be allowed to have different amount of numbers. 

lets say we use this array, which produces the attached output (https://imgur.com/a/4xNUImf)

int[] something = {1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1}

Comment: so using that array, my "map" would be: 
0 0 0 0 1 4

1 2 3 2 1 1

Comment: @5KRU6 thanks for clarification; I was about to say you can use 0 to fill the undecided elements in 1-d array; SO in this case the first row is 0 0 0 0 1 4, six elements; The second row 1 2 3 2 1 1, six elemnts; I will edit my post to provide a new solution for this cse.

Comment: yep thats exactly what i was hoping to do with the blank spots.thanks

Answer (score 0):

So If I am reading this correctly if L is the length of your array you want to add the nth and L-1-nth element of the array and store the result in an array. I through this together quickly so I did not handle what happens if the input array is of odd length (your question did not specify).

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] something = {1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(addValues(something)));

    }
    public static int [] addValues(int [] input){
        int[] output = new int[input.length / 2];
        for(int i = 0; i<input.length/2; i++){
            output[i] = input[i] + input[input.length -1 - i ];
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I think this will work for the case where the are an arbitrary number of rows.
The main insite into how this work is in the grid below.

```
0  1  2  3  4  5 :row 0
11 10 9  8  7  6 :row 1
12 13 14 15 16 17:row 2
23 22 21 20 19 18:row 3
```

So whether the output index is going up or down is determined by the row number and every time we hit an input index that is the same size as our output array we need to stay at the same output index.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] something = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2 };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(addValues(something, 6)));

    }

    public static int[] addValues(int[] input, int row_lenth) {
        int[] output = new int[row_lenth];
        int output_index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (i % row_lenth != 0) {
                if ((i / row_lenth) % 2 == 0) {
                    output_index++;
                } else {
                    output_index--;
                }
            }
            output[output_index] += input[i];
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. this works great, but as you mentioned (and i shoudlve), the array can be of odd length

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Stckoverq {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What is the size of array? ");
    int size = sn.nextInt();
    System.out.print("What is length of the row?");
    int len = sn.nextInt();
    int ind = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    //variable 'ind' is for getting the element from arr[] array at index ind
    int rac[][] = new int[size/len][len];
    //variable 'i' and 'j' is for storing rows and column elements respectively in array rac[]
    int arr[] = new int[size];
    System.out.println("Enter array elements: ");
    for(int k=0;k<size;k++)
        arr[k] = sn.nextInt();
    while(ind!=arr.length)
    {
        if(j==len) {
            j=0;    //Reset column index
            i++;    //Increase row index
        }
        rac[i][j] = arr[ind];
        ind++;
        j++;    //Increase column index
    }
    //Now print the rows and columns................
    for(int r =0;r<size/len;r++) {
        for(int c=0;c<len;c++)
            System.out.print(rac[r][c]+"\t");
        System.out.println();
        }
    int sum[] = new int[len];
    //this array sum[] is used to store sum of all row elements.
    int s = 0;
    for(int c=0;c<len;c++) {
        for(int r =0;r<size/len;r++)
            s += rac[r][c];
        sum[c] = s;
        s = 0;
        }
    for(int x: sum)
        System.out.print(x+"\t");
}
}
```